# Enemy patrol script using NavMeshAgent

Tags: c#, ai, unity3d

I'm piecing together an `Enemy` script to attach to my characters. This is the portion that related the a game objects ability to patrol to given locations. Basically, `patrolPoisitions` are exactly what they say; they are defined in the editor. This is only the pertinent portion of the code, so there might be some straggler variables. I think I deleted them all though.

I am still very new to game development as well as Unity, so are there any suggestions on how to improve this code?

```
public float BaseAcceleration = 10.0f;
public float BaseSpeed = 5.0f;
public float IncreasedAccelerationFactor = 10.0f;
public float IncreasedSpeedFactor = 5.0f;
public float AlertCoolDownTime = 5.0f;
public float AlertDistance = 15.0f;
public float AttackDistance = 10.0f;
public float StoppingDistance = 0.0f;

private NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent = null;
public List<Vector3> patrolPositions = new List<Vector3>();
public float PatrolHoldTime = 0.0f;
private Vector3 StartPosition;
private int patrolPositionIndex = 0;
private bool isAtPatrolPosition = false;
private Vector3 CurrentDestination;

void Start () {
            navMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ();
            StartPosition = transform.position;
    }

void Update () {
            if (CurrentTarget) {
                    navMeshAgent.SetDestination (CurrentTarget.position);
            } else {
                    Patrol ();
            }

            SetNavMeshProperties ();
    }

#region Patrol Methods
void Patrol() {
            Vector3 Position = transform.position;
            if (patrolPositions != null && patrolPositions.Count > 1) {
                    Vector3 Destination = patrolPositions [patrolPositionIndex];
                    if (Destination != Position && CurrentDestination != Destination) {
                            Debug.Log (String.Format ("Patrol plotting route to {0}", Destination.ToString ()));
                            navMeshAgent.SetDestination (Destination);
                            CurrentDestination = Destination;
                            isAtPatrolPosition = false;
                    } else if (Destination == Position && !isAtPatrolPosition) {
                            isAtPatrolPosition = true;
                            Debug.Log (String.Format ("Patrol waiting {0} seconds", PatrolHoldTime));
                            StartCoroutine (Wait (PatrolHoldTime));
                    }
            } else if (Position != StartPosition) {
                    navMeshAgent.SetDestination (StartPosition);
            }
    }
void SetNavMeshProperties() {
            navMeshAgent.acceleration = BaseAcceleration;
            navMeshAgent.speed = BaseSpeed;
            navMeshAgent.stoppingDistance = StoppingDistance;
    }


IEnumerator Wait(float duration) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (duration);
            if (patrolPositionIndex < patrolPositions.Count - 1) {
                    patrolPositionIndex++;
            } else {
                    patrolPositionIndex = 0;
            }
            isAtPatrolPosition = false;
            Debug.Log (String.Format ("Patrol position index {0}", patrolPositionIndex.ToString ()));
    }
#endregion
```

Answer (score 4):

Your indentation and Java-style braces make it very hard to follow. Compare this:

> ```
> void Patrol() {
>             Vector3 Position = transform.position;
>             if (patrolPositions != null && patrolPositions.Count > 1) {
>                     Vector3 Destination = patrolPositions [patrolPositionIndex];
>                     if (Destination != Position && CurrentDestination != Destination) {
>                             Debug.Log (String.Format ("Patrol plotting route to {0}", Destination.ToString ()));
>                             navMeshAgent.SetDestination (Destination);
>                             CurrentDestination = Destination;
>                             isAtPatrolPosition = false;
>                     } else if (Destination == Position && !isAtPatrolPosition) {
>                             isAtPatrolPosition = true;
>                             Debug.Log (String.Format ("Patrol waiting {0} seconds", PatrolHoldTime));
>                             StartCoroutine (Wait (PatrolHoldTime));
>                     }
>             } else if (Position != StartPosition) {
>                     navMeshAgent.SetDestination (StartPosition);
>             }
>     }
> ```

to that:

```
void Patrol() 
{
    Vector3 Position = transform.position;
    if (patrolPositions != null && patrolPositions.Count > 1) 
    {
        Vector3 Destination = patrolPositions[patrolPositionIndex];
        if (Destination != Position && CurrentDestination != Destination) 
        {
             Debug.Log(String.Format("Patrol plotting route to {0}", Destination.ToString()));
             navMeshAgent.SetDestination(Destination);
             CurrentDestination = Destination;
             isAtPatrolPosition = false;
        } 
        else if (Destination == Position && !isAtPatrolPosition) 
        {
             isAtPatrolPosition = true;
             Debug.Log(String.Format("Patrol waiting {0} seconds", PatrolHoldTime));
             StartCoroutine(Wait(PatrolHoldTime));
        }
    } 
    else if (Position != StartPosition) 
    {
        navMeshAgent.SetDestination(StartPosition);
    }
}
```

---

I'd remove this comment:

```
// Use this for initialization
```

And I'd avoid `#region` blocks - you're not showing your entire class, but regions are typically a sign that too many things are going on, and can often be extracted into their own class (or method, when the region is defined within a method's body).

---

I don't understand why a method called `Wait` would return an `IEnumerator`, and it seems a bit counter-intuitive that `Wait` would have the side-effect of changing the `patrolPositionIndex` - could the method have a more descriptive name?

---

These initializations are redundant, since they're initializing to the default value for their type:

```
private NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent = null;
```

```
public float StoppingDistance = 0.0f;
```

```
public float PatrolHoldTime = 0.0f;
```

```
private int patrolPositionIndex = 0;
```

```
private bool isAtPatrolPosition = false;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input, but are you familiar with the Unity development platform? I believe if you were, you would understand the redundant initialization as they are set as components within the object itself. If you are and I am actually missing something just let me know. I am still pretty new to Unity development. The regions are more of just a bad habit I picked up, I usually only leave them during development, for some reason it helps me navigate more quickly. I usually always remove them after I'm done with a particular section. Also, the terrible indentation... a casualty of the..

Comment: ... attached IDE, Monodevelop. It's awful. :( As far as the `IEnumerator` part goes, in Unity, any coroutines must return an `I` value so they can be iterated through per the `Update` method. May not be the exact reason why, but I just know it has to return this way per Unity setup. And yeah, that comment shouldn't be there. That's auto-generated commenting I missed when copy/pasting. I went ahead and deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to game development!

First, an important thing that will help you for the rest of your career: the modulo operator.  The code `int y = x % 5` will assign the value "x modulo 5" to y, which can be thought of as the remainder of x after being divided by 5.  So, 3 modulo 5 is 3, 4 modulo 5 is 4, 5 modulo 5 is 0, and 6 modulo 5 is 1.  This will save you from code like:

```
if (patrolPositionIndex < patrolPositions.Count - 1) {
    patrolPositionIndex++;
} else {
    patrolPositionIndex = 0;
}
```

which can be rewritten to:

```
patrolPositionIndex = (patrolPositionIndex + 1) % patrolPositions.Count;
```

Another thing that immediately jumps out is your setting of the nav agent properties in the `Update()` method.  Since `Update()` get called every frame, you are wasting a lot of time to set values every frame with the same values that are already there.  These calls should be moved to `Start()` or `Awake()` which are only called once.

Finally, I would move the code to direct the agent to the next spot to the bottom of the coroutine so the code has a logical flow.  In `Update()` all you do is wait for the agent to reach its destination and in the coroutine, you wait for a while and then send the agent on its way.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(NavMeshAgent))]
public class Patrol : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float BaseAcceleration = 10f;
    public float BaseSpeed = 5f;
    public float StoppingDistance = 0f;
    public float StopThresholdDistance = .1f;
    public float PatrolHoldTime = 0f;

    public List<Vector3> PatrolPositions = new List<Vector3>();

    private NavMeshAgent _agent;
    private Transform _thisTransform;
    private int _patrolPositionIndex = 0f;
    private bool _moving = false;

    public void Awake()
    {
        _agent = gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        _thisTransform = gameObject.transform;

        // make sure the game object is set up with the things it needs
        if (_agent == null || PatrolPositions.Count < 1)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // set the nav agent properties once on startup
        _agent.acceleration = BaseAcceleration;
        _agent.speed = BaseSpeed;
        _agent.stoppingDistance = StoppingDistance;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        // if we're waiting, don't do anything
        if (!_moving) return;

        // get the distance between the agent and where they are supposed to be
        var distance = (_agent.destination - _thisTransform.position).magnitude;

        // if the distance is below a threshold
        if (distance < StopThresholdDistance)
        {
            StartCoroutine(WaitAndGo());
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator WaitAndGo()
    {
        // stop moving
        _moving = false;

        // wait some amount of time
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(PatrolHoldTime);

        // get the next position in the list
        _patrolPositionIndex++;
        _patrolPositionIndex %= PatrolPositions.Count;

        // tell the agent to move
        _agent.SetDestination(PatrolPositions[_patrolPositionIndex]);

        // switch the state of this class to wait for the agent to get to the next point
        _moving = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah the mod operator! I am very familiar with it, but for some reason it never quite hit me that it would be appropriate here! This is the first game I've attempted, coming from business development and it's an ENTIRELY different frame of mind for sure.